# Is Safari's RTCDataChannel implementation completely broken?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, webrtc

I'm trying to get a string to pass from one browser window to another through an `RTCDataConnection`.

There are numerous examples of this working, such as the one here:
https://gitlab.com/lesmana/webrtc-without-signaling-server

These work quite well in most browsers, however, in (at least the desktop version of) Safari 12, attempting to connect ultimately results in a "failed" message generated in the connection state after the offer / answer back and fourth is said and done.

Adding the WebRTC `adapter.js` doesn't fix anything.

But further, it seems as though every example or tutorial that supposedly demonstrates `RTCDataChannel` communication ... breaks in Safari.

Is this supposed to work? I cannot find any relevant issues in [bugs.webkit.org](https://bugs.webkit.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claims that WebRTC can be used without a signaling server should be taken with a grain of salt in general.. Safari does behave a bit differently when used without getUserMedia in order to avoid leaking IP addresses.

In this case, you are exchanging pc.localDescription.sdp via copy-paste. That SDP does *not* include the local host candidates (even though you get them in the onicecandidate event). I've filed a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198887).

If you want to workaround this in the meantime, note any candidate with 'typ host' [here](https://gitlab.com/lesmana/webrtc-without-signaling-server/blob/master/common.js#L26) and add it [here](https://gitlab.com/lesmana/webrtc-without-signaling-server/blob/master/offering.js#L36) (while making sure the sdp is still valid and contains a trailing newline etc), same for the answerer.

Comment: Great answer. The output of the SDP is quite deceiving in that it definitely makes look like the local host candidates are included.

Comment: when using a stun server, srflx candidates are included. This *may* even work on some NATs. Not on others. Search for "NAT hairpinning" if you want the full story ;-)